# Configure CKEDITOR not to fix HTML for a certain custom tag

Tags: ckeditor

I use CKEditor within a template system where I use custom tags and then my PHP backend will replace the custom tags found in the HTML with data.

For example, on a tutorial I may have a standard set of instructions on how to do something, but certain examples require extra instructions. In a situation like that I would insert the <%Extra_Instructions%> custom tag into the html and then the php backend would replace that with the instructions for that page.

So in a list, I would do something like:

```
<ol>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <%Extra_Instructions%>
 <li>You are all done!</li>
</ol>
```

The problem is that CKeditor detects that the custom tag is not correct html and automatically moves it outside of the list.  So the source would become:

```
<%Extra_Instructions%>
<ol>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <li>Step 1</li>
 <%Extra_Instructions%>
 <li>You are all done!</li>
</ol>
```

Is there a way to configure Ckeditor not to do this for certain tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place these tags in places like inside `<ul>`, then the only solution here is to use [`config.protectedSource`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource). Matching fragments of data will be transformed into HTML comments during editing. This of course makes them invisible to a user, but it allows to keep them in places where other elements cannot be located. E.g. inside `<ul>` you can only have `<li>` so your custom tags can only be replaced by comments or `<li>`. Protected source gives you the former and the latter is a much more complicated option because you would like to make some constraints about editability of these tags.

Example usage of `config.protectedSource`:

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<%[\s\S]*?%>/g );
```

Comment: I have this already in my config. I also have the show protected plugin installed as well. The minute you click on the source button, or save the form contents, the  <%Extra_Instructions%> is moved to above the <ol> tag.

Comment: Most likely this happens because you installed the show protected plugin. As I wrote - you cannot display anything in between `<li>` elements and this plugin will not change that unless it's very smart. That's why your data is changed.

Comment: Yup, the show protected plugin is the problem. Thanks for helping.